# Jest results differ locally vs GitHub actions

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I have a TypeScript project that I'm working on covering with Jest. Currently, my suite of 11 tests pass both locally and if when used with [Act](https://github.com/nektos/act).

Here is my `run_tests.yml` file:

```
name: Run Jest Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
      - run: npm install -g yarn
      - run: yarn install
      - run: yarn test
```

[Here](https://github.com/jamespericles/Result-Bot/actions/runs/5955722262/job/16154954716) is my latest run, where you can see most values I test for are undefined, which of course does not happen locally.